# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Queue\RedisQueue::readyNow()

Tags: laravel-horizon

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Queue\RedisQueue::readyNow() at AutoScaler.php 80

for Laravel Horizon

Comment: The `readyNow()` method is part of Horizon's `RedisQueue` extension. It seems like the application is calling Laravel's built-in `RedisQueue` instead. Perhaps some part of the application bootstrap process is overriding the binding that Horizon's service provider adds to the container. Is the Horizon package auto-loaded?

Comment: Hi Xyrin did you manage to sollve this issue?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this??? I've upgraded to Laravel 9 and am facing this error. Installing composer install with dev dependencies stops it

Answer (score 0):

FYI if anyone is experiencing this and landed here from google. Check that "spatie/laravel-ignition" is in require and not require-dev! This is what fixed for me on Laravel 9.

```
composer require spatie/laravel-ignition
```